# Pyrosm Loading Nodes and Edges - Input must be valid geometry objects

Tags: python, graph, openstreetmap, shapely

Good morning all,

I am trying to load a .pbf file using the pyrosm library's [documentation](https://pyrosm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#export-to-networkx-osmnx).

My code below.

```
import pyrosm

# Get filepath to test PBF dataset
fp = pyrosm.get_data("wisconsin")

# Initialize the OSM object 
osm = pyrosm.OSM(fp)

nodes, edges = osm.get_network(nodes=True)

print(f"Nodes {nodes} and edges {edges}")
```

I get the following error which seems to come from the library itself.

**TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: MULTILINESTRING ((-89.5 44.5, -89.5 44.5), (-89.5 44.5, -89.5 44.5), (-89.5 44.5, -89.5 44.5), (-89.5 44.5, -89.5 44.5), (-89.5 44.5, -89.5 44.5))**

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Thanks a lot